# Optional Chaining with typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, graphql

I have had an issue a number of times where I am getting to grips with Typescript.
I request a graphql data set on a parent component for example, and pass that down to the child component e.g `data`

Now, the data more than likely has not been received straight away so I check for this via e.g
`data?.myCarId` using optional chaining.

However my understanding was that if `data` was not filled or non null, then it what stop checking the rest.

But I get a typescript error similar to:

```
 Property 'myCarId` does not exist on type `Cartypes | null)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Parent Component

```
export const CarsTable: React.FC = () => {

const getData = graphQlCall(getCars)

<ChildComponent data={getData}/>

}
```

Child component

```
export const Car: React.FC = ({data}) => {

const cars = data?.myCarId    //<< error happens here

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code?

Comment: Updated with extremely simplified example/use case

Comment: It works like you expect https://tsplay.dev/1WGG2W. What does your `Cartypes` interface look like?

Comment: If data was null however, until the response was received would that still work? e.g in a yet to be fulfilled promise